# Rails and gem files

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I've got a Ruby wrapper for some REST APIs in a gem file. I'm trying to integrate this gem in a rails project and I have been wondering (being new to this...)

1. To establish the connection I need to provide a Token and an account number. Where would it be the best place to save the ruby file with the token on the rails project?

Many thanks

Comment: A file with name of that gem in config/initializers. And use env variables to define this variables.

Comment: Thanks @FlorentFerry I'll try that... Now, when working on Ruby files I need to insert require 'api_name' at the beginning of the page. Is there a "global" place for that on rails so I don't have to insert the require on each erb file?